# Consolidate records, every column the same data except one column

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have some records that look like this

```
barcode:123, event:ASSIGN, event_datetime 9/23/2018 10am

barcode:123, event:CLOSE, event_datetime 9/23/2018 11am

barcode:123, event:ASSIGN, event_datetime 9/30/2018 10am

barcode:123, event:CLOSE, event_datetime 9/30/2018 11am
```

I would like to consolidate these 4 records into 2 records that would look like:

```
barcode:123, event:close, event_start_datetime 9/23/18 10am event_end_datetime 9/23/2018 11am

barcode:123, event:close, event_start_datetime 9/30/2018 10am event_end_datetime 9/30/2018 11am
```

I've tried the obvious `MIN/MAX` combinations, but since all the other columns are identical data (basically they look like duplicates except one column) it will consolidate into one column with the min/max combo.

I was thinking something with a `rank()` but it sounds like it was getting pretty complicated, and I could use some help.

Comment: I don't understand how you get the output from the input. Just guessing: for each ASSIGN, you take the first "future" occurrence of CLOSE (perhaps for the same barcode) and you pair them for the one row in the output? How do you even know that a CLOSE is for the most recent ASSIGN, and not for a much older one? And, are you guaranteeing that all "events" will be properly paired? What if the input data has three ASSIGN but only two CLOSE rows?

Comment: Also show us the query that you've tried

Comment: You won't be able to solve it through aggregate functions. Left join the table onto itself on column that are "duplicates" and filter further to have one row per event.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant of answers but try out the below

```
select barcode, last_event_act, max(max_event_start), max(max_event_end) , event_datetime from 
(
select barcode, last_event_act, 
max(event_end) over (partition by to_char(event_end, 'mm/dd/YYYY')) max_event_end, 
max(event_start) over (partition by to_char(event_start, 'mm/dd/YYYY')) max_event_start, event_datetime
from 
(
select  barcode, last_value(EVENT) OVER (PARTITION BY to_char(EVENT_DATETIME, 'mm/dd/YYYY') ) as last_event_act, 
case 
    when event = 'CLOSE' then event_datetime 
    END 
 as event_end, 
 case 
     when event = 'ASSIGN' then event_datetime 
     END 
as event_start , max(to_char(event_datetime, 'mm/dd/yyyy')) over (partition by to_char(event_datetime, 'mm/dd/YYYY')) as event_datetime from barc
)
    )
    group by barcode, last_event_act, event_datetime
```